# how to reorder contents of LinearLayout in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, toolbar

I started developing an App using Android Studio and have a Question.

in MainActivity I have 2 Views.
    1. toolbar (with Buttons on it)
    2. VideoView

my MainActivity allows only Landscape-View
normaly the toolbar is above Videoview and the App works properly.

I want to get the user the possiblility to set it under VideoView.

in my MainActivity.java

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout =   (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    myVideoView= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    //myLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    myLinearLayout.removeView(myVideoView);
    myLinearLayout.removeView(toolbar);

    myLinearLayout.addView(myVideoView);
    myLinearLayout.addView(toolbar);
```

if I run the App is nothing to see. I can not see the toolbar and Videoview on MainActivity. It is a blank WIndow only with my Background image sets using

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.myBackground);
```

what is wrong with my code?

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:text="b1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <!--Mute Unmute Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:text="b2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.mrezaeian.toolbar_test.MainActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update:

I found out that depends on the following parameters:

```html
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

if I change the layout_height to other value e.g 300dp, the Toolbar appears.

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: Add your xml file